# Can I set the keyboard accessory of the mobile device in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I created a hybrid app with Vue.js. Can I write a keyboard accessoryView in Vue code that exists in ios? Or is there a way to fix the custom accessoryView by detecting the keyboard coming up and calculating the height? I failed in both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that [Visual Viewport API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Visual_Viewport_API) can be useful as shown in this tweet: https://twitter.com/rikschennink/status/1361598959828037633

```js
visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  console.log(window.innerHeight);
  console.log(visualViewport.height);
})
```

But for the specific `accessoryView` property/method, I guess that you need to add some iOS tags for this question to be noticed by those people.